# How do you clear the files inside a docker container?

Tags: docker, portainer

This is probably because I don't understand something about how docker works, but I'm trying to get all the data from a container cleared. In this case the stack is for a jellyfin server.

I've tried removing the container and recreating it, I've tried removing the stack and recreating it, but no matter what I do as soon as I navigate to the jellyfin server in a browser all the accounts and metadata are still there!

All access is being done through Portainer, to delete a container I'm stopping it, then clicking remove:
[image]

To Delete a stack, I'm deleting any containers it has, then stopping it and deleting it:
[image]

Comment: Deleting a container will delete everything in its local filesystem, unless you've told Docker to persist data somewhere else through some kind of mount (`docker run -v` option or Compose `volumes:`).  How are you starting the container?  Can you edit the question to include a [mcve] demonstrating the problem?

Comment: @DavidMaze I'm managing the container through Portainer, so I'm not familiar with any of the commands you mention, I'll include a bit more info, but its just selecting the container, stopping it, and removing it and for the stack its just selecting it and clicking remove

Answer (score 0):

My solution was deleting the config directories that existed outside the container. When I set up jellyfin via docker-compose one of the directories you set up is a config directory, which means the files created in there are outside the docker container, and persist no matter how many times you delete it.

If anyone else is having difficulty with getting a docker container to reset, check what directories it has access to.